# Need help speeding up my solution for Project Euler #650

Tags: python, performance

So Ive been working on project Euler problem #650, and it generates the correct answer for smaller values, but they are looking for the solution to values up to 20,000.  At the speed my code is currently running that will take like a billion years.  Any tips for improving this code and making it more efficient/faster would be appreciated.  Here is a link to the problem:  https://projecteuler.net/problem=650

and the code

```
from scipy.special import comb
import math
import time

t0 = time.time()

def B(x):
    #takes product of binomial coefficients
    product = 1
    for i in range(x + 1):
        product *= comb(x, i, exact=True)
    return product



def D(y):
    #Sums all divisors of the product of binom. coefficients
    x = B(y)
    summation = []
    for i in range(1, int(math.sqrt(x)) + 1):
        if x % i == 0:
            summation.append(i)
            summation.append(x // i)
    summation = list(dict.fromkeys(summation))
    return sum(summation)


def S(z):
    """sums up all the sums of divisors of the product of the binomial 
    coefficients"""
    sigma = []
    for i in range(1, z + 1):
        sigma.append(D(i))
    return sum(sigma)

print(S(20000))

t1 = time.time()

total = t1 - t0


print(total)
```

Comment: Please put the problem description in the question, not just a link to it.

Comment: Well unrelated to problem, i'd immediately suggest removing print(D(i)) in the first place. You are calculating all twice. :)

Comment: this is better suited for math stackexchange. hint: your brute Force method will never work. you will get nowhere if you do trial division instead of using the divisors you already know from binomial coefficient. and lookup sum of divisors function

Answer (score 1):

me too
but you can try this

```
from math import factorial

def n_choose_k(n, k):
    if k == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return factorial(n)//((factorial(k))*factorial(n-k))

def B(n):
    prods = []
    for k in range(0, n):
        prods.append(n_choose_k(n, k))
```